# Configuring babel-typescript for Sequelize ORM causes undefined properties

Tags: typescript, sequelize.js, babeljs

There is a problem when using [sequelize-typescript](https://github.com/RobinBuschmann/sequelize-typescript) together with [babel-preset-typescript](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-preset-typescript). Columns should be retrieved through the [Object.defineProperty()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/defineProperty#custom_setters_and_getters) but when an existing property already exists it is skipped [see source here](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/main/lib/model.js#L1242-L1248). When running the code with regular typescript implementation with Sequelize† everything works but when implementing babel-typescript the properties remain.

**Question**: How should I define my babel configuration so that the properties are properly ignored?

### Babel definitions (babel.config.js)

I've tried two Babel definitions, one that has all desired features & one that requires explicit definitions.

#### Full definition

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        regenerator: true,
      },
    ],
    "babel-plugin-inline-import",
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
    ["@babel/proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-optional-chaining",
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        alias: {
          "~": "./src",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/typescript"],
};
```

#### Tiny explicit definition

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
    ["@babel/proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
    "@babel/proposal-async-generator-functions",
    "@babel/proposal-object-rest-spread",
    "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
  ],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/typescript"],
};
```

### Background & details

You can find a regular non-babel example for testing [here](https://github.com/gforge/express-sequelize-ts-example), the branch [babel_build](https://github.com/gforge/express-sequelize-ts-example/tree/babel_build) and [babel_explicit](https://github.com/gforge/express-sequelize-ts-example/tree/babel_explicit) contain different babel-implementations.

The gist of defining a table is a trivial case of adding decorators to the code:

```
import { Table, Column, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript'

@Table
class Person extends Model {
  @Column
  name: string

  @Column
  birthday: Date
}
```

The problem is that if we then retrieve a case through:

```js
const p = await Person.findOne({ name: "John Doe" })
console.log(p)
```

we get:

```
Person {
 dataValues: {
   id: 1,
   name: "John Doe",
   birthday: null
 },
  _previousDataValues: {
   id: 1,
   name: "John Doe",
   birthday: null
 },
  _changed: Set(0) {},
  _options: {
    isNewRecord: false,
    _schema: null,
    _schemaDelimiter: '',
    raw: true,
    attributes: [
      'id',
      'name',
      'birthday'
    ]
  },
  isNewRecord: false,
  name: undefined,
  birthday: undefined,
}
```

note the last two rows with `undefined`.

### Update - using `declare`

It seems that the correct definitions should be using the [`declare`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#the-usedefineforclassfields-flag-and-the-declare-property-modifier) keyword. While this should solve the issue it doesn't work in practice.

```
import { Table, Column, Model } from 'sequelize-typescript'

@Table
class Person extends Model {
  @Column
  declare name: string

  @Column
  declare birthday: Date
}
```

with the config:

```js
module.exports = {
  plugins: [
    ["@babel/plugin-transform-typescript", { allowDeclareFields: true }],
    [
      "@babel/plugin-transform-runtime",
      {
        regenerator: true,
      },
    ],
    "babel-plugin-transform-typescript-metadata",
    ["@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators", { legacy: true }],
    ["@babel/proposal-class-properties", { loose: true }],
    [
      "module-resolver",
      {
        alias: {
          "~": "./src",
        },
      },
    ],
  ],
  presets: ["@babel/preset-env"],
};
```

Unfortunately, the issue is not resolved but seems that `declare` is more in line with the intended use.

† this is most likely independent of the `sequelize-typescript` add-ons

Comment: There are an open issue: https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11675

Answer (score 1):

## Update 2022-01-21

You should use `declare` instead of `public ...`.

For example:

```js
class User extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>
  implements UserAttributes {
  //public id!: number; // Note that the `null assertion` `!` is required in strict mode.
  declare id: number;

  //public name!: string;
  declare name: string;

  //public preferredName!: string | null; // for nullable fields
  declare preferredName: string | null;

  // timestamps!
  //public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  declare readonly createdAt: Date;
```

Source:

- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/13877/files
- https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11675#issuecomment-1003765448

## Original answer

From https://sequelize.org/master/manual/typescript.html, the *TypeScript* definition for model initialization is correct, but the documentation is not correct!

When you use the *null assertion* (`public id!: number; // Note that the "null assertion" "!" is required in strict mode`), this make the attribute as `undefined` at instance initialization.

My idea is to force the model initialization using `getDataValue()` at *Model Constructor* and avoid to use the recommended *null assertion*.

### Example

```js
import {
  BuildOptions,
  Sequelize,
  Model,
  Optional,
} from "sequelize";

const sequelize = new Sequelize("mysql://root:asd123@localhost:3306/mydb");

// These are all the attributes in the User model
interface UserAttributes {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  //preferredName!: string | null;
  preferredName: string | null;
}

// Some attributes are optional in `User.build` and `User.create` calls
interface UserCreationAttributes extends Optional<UserAttributes, "id"> {}

class User extends Model<UserAttributes, UserCreationAttributes>
  implements UserAttributes {
  //public id!: number; // Note that the `null assertion` `!` is required in strict mode.
  public id: number;

  //public name!: string;
  public name: string;

  //public preferredName!: string | null; // for nullable fields
  public preferredName: string | null;

  // timestamps!
  //public readonly createdAt!: Date;
  public readonly createdAt: Date;

  //public readonly updatedAt!: Date;
  public readonly updatedAt: Date;

  /**
   * Initialization to fix Sequelize Issue #11675.
   *
   * @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66515762/configuring-babel-typescript-for-sequelize-orm-causes-undefined-properties
   * @see https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/issues/11675
   * @ref #SEQUELIZE-11675
   */
  constructor(values?: TCreationAttributes, options?: BuildOptions) {
    super(values, options);

    // All fields should be here!
    this.id = this.getDataValue('id');
    this.name = this.getDataValue('name');
    this.preferredName = this.getDataValue('preferredName');
    this.createdAt = this.getDataValue('createdAt');
    this.updatedAt = this.getDataValue('updatedAt');
  }
}
```